# Why is innerHTML acting weird

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm making a javascript file that uses a loop to make the times tables 1 to 12, but I use css to make a neat feel by making any element with the class of timetable float to the right. However the divs which seperate each time table and have a class of timetable do not have any children. Im trying to make the p elements which hold one time table be the children of the divs. Here's my code:

```js
    var math = document.getElementById("maths");

     for (var num = 1; num <= 12; num++) {
         math.innerHTML += "<div class=\"timetable\">";
         for (var currentMath = 1; currentMath <= 12; currentMath++) {
             math.innerHTML += "<p>" + num + " x " + currentMath + " = " + (num * currentMath) + " 
      </p>";
         }
         math.innerHTML += "</div>";
     }
```

Expected HTML:

`<div class="timetable"><p>1 x 1 = 1</p>....</div>`

HTML:

`<div class="timetable"></div><p>1x1 = 1</p>...`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your issue is that you are trying to assign unclosed elements to `innerHTML`. Strings you assign here must always be *complete*.

Comment: This has been closed for the wrong reason. It is not about missing event listeners after using `innerHTML`; it's about assigning unclosed HTML tags first only to close them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please create HTML element using [**document.createElement()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and append the child elements (which is considered as best practice) instead of assigning it as a string.

With the help of [**appendChild()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) , you can append child element to the parent.

**Working Example:**

```js
const math = document.getElementById("maths");

 for (let num = 1; num <= 12; num++) {
     const timeTable = document.createElement('div');
     timeTable.classList.add('timetable');
     for (let currentMath = 1; currentMath <= 12; currentMath++) {
          const child = document.createElement('p');
          child.textContent = num + " x " + currentMath + " = " + (num * currentMath)
          timeTable.appendChild(child);
     }
     math.appendChild(timeTable);
 }
```

```html
<div id="maths"></div>
```

Comment: If you're argumenting with best practices, how come you still use `var`?

Comment: @connexo, Sorry missed that part :). Updated now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Q:** Why is `innerHTML` acting weird?

**A:** Because you're doing **weird** stuff with it.

Your issue is that you are trying to assign unclosed elements to `innerHTML`. Strings you assign here must always be *complete*, because any string you assign is going to be parsed to actual, valid HTML. This means that the way you are doing things the browser will close the unclosed div for you:

```
math.innerHTML += "<div class=\"timetable\">";
```

will result in the browser closing the `div` for you:

```
<div class="timetable"></div>
```

After that, you append `<p>....whatever...</p>` to `innerHTML` repeatedly in a loop, resulting in this `innerHTML`:

```
<div class="timetable"></div>
<p>....whatever...</p>
<p>....whatever...</p>
<p>....whatever...</p>
```

As you can see, the `p` elements are not children of the `div.timetable`.

To fix your issue, just build your string **before** assigning it (and use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to do that):

```js
const math = document.getElementById("maths");
let html = '';

for (let num = 1; num <= 12; num++) {
    html += `<div class="timetable">`;
    for (let currentMath = 1; currentMath <= 12; currentMath++) {
        html += `<p>${num} x ${currentMath} = ${num * currentMath}</p>`;
    }
    html += "</div>";
}
math.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="maths"></div>
```

Also, don't use  `var` any more in 2022, use `const` as a default, and use `let` if you know you will have to repeatedly assign to the variable. `var` should only be used if you explicitly need the specific scoping behavior it has.

Answer (score -1):

The below code should work. You didn't add any HTML though so I am not sure it will work on your end but try it...

```js
var math = document.getElementById("maths").innerHTML;
var code = math;
for (var num = 1; num <= 12; num++) {
  code += "<div class=\"timetable\">";
  for (var currentMath = 1; currentMath <= 12; currentMath++) {
    code += "<p>" + num + " x " + currentMath + " = " + (num * currentMath) + " </p>";
  }
  code += "</div>";
  document.getElementById("maths").innerHTML += code;
  code = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="maths"></div>
```

Comment: `code` should be initialized to an empty string rather than the `#math` HTMLDivElement object. Fix that and it should work.

Comment: I expect him to create his own div with math ID. That’s why I didn’t add on my own

Comment: Any reason for downvoting

Comment: Any existing content of  `#math`, say a header element,  would be duplicated in output.